# Embed a JSON file in an SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, include

Can I use **include** in actionscript in some form?

```
var somevar = include "file.json";
```

Where "file.json" contains JSON data

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'l try to embed json file into swf. Normal Embed sometimes caches files. If you change the json file, sometimes flash does not see changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also may want use ASC 2.0.
(from [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html))
New syntax allows you to use:

```
var h:Object = include 'conf.json'; // where conf.json contains correct JSON
```

Answer (score 9):

It's not this simple, but possible. First, you have to embed a JSON file as is:

```
[Embed(source = 'file.json', mimeType='application/octet-stream')]
private static const YourJSON:Class;
```

Then, to get whatever is embedded (a String, a Bitmap, an SWF), you need to instantiate a variable with this type.

```
var somevar:String=new YourJSON();
```

Then you need to parse the JSON, the correct syntax for this varies by JSON and parsing library (this part is mainly determined by your Flash player target). RafH's answer has a syntax for an array and (IIRC) FP10 compatible library.

Answer (score 0):

No, `include` doesnt return a value and includes are done at compile time, so if the content of the include file change, you need to recompile the swf.

Not sure about you want to do, but it seems like loading / parsing an external JSON data file would be a better approach to look for.

Here is a good example : http://snipplr.com/view/56283/